# optimizing space between many subplots in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am using a loop to create a series of subplots that consist of 2 horizontal plots at each vertical position. There can be many vertical positions, typically 50-100. I  am having trouble optimizing the spacing between the plots. When I create the plots using a loop the more vertical positions I have the larger the gap gets between each horizontal plot. I would like the plots to be much closer together as each horizontal pairing is a related image I am trying to show.

I have tried using the `subplots_adjust(wspace=...)`, `plt.tight_layout()` and `subplots(constrained_layout=True)`, but all without luck.

An example is provided in the attached image for a small array with 10 vertical images (I know I need to adjust the axis labels in the end, but for the purposes of this example that doesn't matter)

What am I missing? I am sure there must be a way to do this.

Thanks

[image: example]

Comment: It looks like you are using `imshow` with `aspect=1`.  Which will make square axes.  If you use square axes, and you have 10x2 there will be a lot of white space unless the aspect ratio of your figure is close to 10x2...

Answer (score 0):

Without code to reproduce your problem it is difficult to predict the solution. Maybe you can make use of `matplotlib.gridspec` in combination with a reasonable `figsize`.

```
# use reasonable figure size
fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize = (8, 20))

# create gridspec
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=2, nrows=8, figure=fig)

# add random plots
for i in range(8):
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[i, 0])
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[i, 1])
    
    # random data
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = np.random.normal(size = (4, 25))
    ax1.scatter(x1, y1, color = 'r')
    ax2.scatter(x2, y2, color = 'b')
```